# Optaplanner: solver.getBestScore and solver.explainBestScore show different results?

Tags: optaplanner

I was running my optaplannner code and received some weird results. During the last step of the local search process before my whole solving process terminated, the solver changed its "current" score. However, the "best score" remained the same.

```
18:30:36.384 DEBUG [main] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:133
>     LS step (205), time spent (200026), score (-250hard/-9soft),     best score (-240hard/-9soft), accepted/selected move count (0/2), picked move (roughplan.domain.Restock@508de524 {50 -> 30}).

18:30:36.384 INFO  [main] o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:151
> Local Search phase (5) ended: time spent (200026), best score (-240hard/-9soft), score calculation speed (35/sec), step total (206).

18:30:36.400 INFO  [main] o.o.c.i.s.DefaultSolver DefaultSolver.java:230
> Solving ended: time spent (200042), best score (-240hard/-9soft), score calculation speed (40/sec), phase total (8), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).
```

If I then want to receive my score, solver.getBestScore and solver.explainBestScore show different results. Also, solver.getBestSolution shows the same score as solver.explainBestScore.

```
> Explanation of score (-250hard/-9soft):

> Score: -240hard/-9soft
```

I repeatedly get this mistake, indepedent of the specific local search phase during which the solver terminates. Running it on "FULL_ASSERT" does not throw any exceptions and I also think that I got all of my @DeepPlanningClone Annotations right.

Comment: Weird on the difference in the second listing - try `NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT`, to fully exclude score corruption.

Comment: The last step does not need to have the best score. Many metaheuristics allow for steps to deteriorate the score in order to escape local optima. Nothing special happening in the first listing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In fact, it was a score corruption that simply occured very rarely. However, I still think it is confusing that at the end of solving, getBestScore and explainBestScore show different results.

Comment: Good point, created an issue: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-1892